# paramiko ssh.connect - what arguments to send?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm really really new to `python` and `ssh`.

I'm trying to write a simple program to open `ssh` connection using `python`.
I already have `paramiko`, but the problem I'm having is this:

Using terminal I use the following command to open my `ssh`:

```
ssh username%hostname@gw.cs.huji.ac.il
```

Now I don't know what arguments to send to - `ssh.connect()`

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any ssh commandline syntax that uses the `%` character. (And it's not mentioned in the manpage on OS X, either.) Is it just part of the username?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the user name.. i only now got it :)...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [paramiko documentation](http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/client.html) there is the following example:

```
client = SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect('ssh.example.com')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls -l')
```

You can also specify the username and password when calling [`connect()`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SSHClient-class.html#connect). Here you have the method's signature:

```
connect(self, hostname, port=22, username=None, password=None,
        pkey=None, key_filename=None, timeout=None, allow_agent=True,
        look_for_keys=True, compress=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, iv'e went thorugh the documentation, but still couldn't crack this one.

Comment: @oopsi Still having problems? Or you could fix it?

Comment: @oopsi I first tried to change the policy when keys are missing with `ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())`. After that, while trying to connect I get this exception: `BadAuthenticationType: Bad authentication type (allowed_types=['keyboard-interactive'])`. A quick search in google points out to a bug in paramiko. You might want to directly contact them.

Answer (score 1):

The docs are pretty clear on this one, have a look and see if you can make sense of it - http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SSHClient-class.html#connect

```
connect(self, hostname, port=22, username=None, password=None, pkey=None, key_filename=None, timeout=None, allow_agent=True, look_for_keys=True, compress=False)
```

So for you the command would be

```
ssh.connect('gw.cs.huji.ac.il', username='username%hostname')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for some reason when i try this it throws an exception - Unknown server. when i connect using the shell command it connects me with no problem...