# How to access a remote host with Paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am just getting started on using Paramiko to connect to another host. I can access this host via its internal IP address in my local network and this works fine (both in Python and via `ssh` in the console).

When I try to access the host via its external IP address, however, the access via Paramiko fails while `ssh` in the console still works. The only difference here is that instead of the host's internal IP address I use the machine's external one.

Could anyone please help? Could it be that Paramiko somehow conflicts with the port forwarding I have configured on our router?

Here's my code so far:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

target_host = 'external.IP'
# target_host = 'internal.IP'

# Internal access port for ssh transfer.
# target_port = 22

# External access port for ssh transfer.
target_port = ABCD

pwd = 'my.password'
un = 'my.username'

ssh.connect( hostname = target_host , username = un, password = pwd )

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls -1 .')

print "STDOUT:\n%s\n\nSTDERR:\n%s\n" %( stdout.read(), stderr.read() )
```

Added:

The full error message received is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 25, in 
    ssh.connect( hostname = target_host , username = un, password = pwd )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 251, in connect
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/util.py", line 270, in retry_on_signal
    return function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 251, in 
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused

The only difference between the Python and the console access is the port. Could it be Paramiko always goes via port 22 for ssh? If so, is there a way to direct Paramiko to go through another port?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Any message, timeout, etc? What's in `sshd` logs?

Comment: Where is `ABCD` defined, and to what? `target_port = ABCD` will throw an exception in this code, and the ssh connection will never even be attempted...

Comment: ssh via the bash shell works no prob ...

Comment: @twalberg: I used `ABCD` to mask the actual port used. In my implementation I used an actual numerical value for that port, of course. I validated that I can enter through it using `ssh username@host -p ABCD`. Sorry for not making this clear from the start.

Answer (score 7):

Output of your script on my host with this change:
`stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls -1 /root|head -n 5')`

File `1.py`:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
target_host = '127.0.0.1'
target_port = 22
pwd = 'password'
un = 'root'
ssh.connect( hostname = target_host , username = un, password = pwd )
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls -1 /root|head -n 5')
print "STDOUT:\n%s\n\nSTDERR:\n%s\n" %( stdout.read(), stderr.read() )
# For Python3
# print("STDOUT:\n%s\n\nSTDERR:\n%s\n" %( stdout.read(), stderr.read() ))
```

Run `python 1.py`:

```
STDOUT:
~
1
1421750672-TWya15.png
1.py
7


STDERR:
```

I think you need `ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())` avoid.

```
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be
established.
RSA key fingerprint is 
22:fb:16:3c:24:7f:60:99:4f:f4:57:d6:d1:09:9e:28.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting 
(yes/no)? 

import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(
    paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('127.0.0.1', username='jesse', 
    password='lol')
```

[SSH PROGRAMMING WITH PARAMIKO | COMPLETELY DIFFERENT](http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different)

Comment: Hi, sorry ... I am not sure I understand your important sentence `I think you need ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) avoid`. Could you please explain? As for the output you are getting, this is exactly what I would expect and am getting when connecting to the host via its local network IP address.

Comment: Please note: Your sample code specifies a port but never actually uses that value. Could it be that Paramiko always goes through port 22? This would explain why the external IP access in my case failed because my router had another port opened.

Answer (score 0):

OK ... I have now solved the problem: The issue was indeed that in my script there was no specification of the port through which to go. Paramiko therefore defaults to port 22 - which was not open on my router.

Thanks to @betabandido who provided the full method signature in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551043/paramiko-ssh-connect-what-arguments-to-send).

The fix to my problem was to include the port specification in the `connect` statement as follows:

`ssh.connect( hostname = target_host, port = target_port, username = un, password = pwd )`

Thanks to all who contributed!